# Não estou conseguindo realizar um onMouseEnter no react

Tags: react, javascript-eventos, css-hover, eventos-do-mouse

Estou querendo ter o seguinte resultado:

Ao passar o mouse por cima de uma imagem quero que o paragrafo com classname chamado 'text' seja alterado, da mesma forma que ao tirar o mouse da imagem ele volte ao texto anterior e ao passar por cima de outra imagem diferente, altere novamente o paragrafo classname 'text' com outro texto.

Fiz o seguinte codigo a baixo porem, não estou conseguindo ter o resultado que eu gostaria, alguem poderia me ajudar nessa duvida?

```
import html from '../../assets/skills/html.svg'
import css from '../../assets/skills/css.svg'
import js from '../../assets/skills/js.svg'
import react from '../../assets/skills/react.svg'
import sass from '../../assets/skills/sass.svg'
import styled from '../../assets/skills/styled.svg'
import tailwind from '../../assets/skills/tailwind.svg'
import bootstrap from '../../assets/skills/bootstrap.svg'
import { ContainerSkills, SkillsGrid, SkillsTitle } from './styles'



export default function Skills(){

    const change=()=>{
    
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('.html')){
            document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML = 'esse é o html'
    
        }else if(document.getElementsByClassName('.css')){
        document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML = 'esse é o css'
        }
    }
    
    
    return(

        <ContainerSkills>        
                        <SkillsTitle>
                            <h1>Habilidades</h1>
                        </SkillsTitle>
                        <SkillsGrid>
                            <li>
                                <img className='html' onMouseEnter={change}  src={html}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img className='css' onMouseEnter={change} src={css}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={js}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={react}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={sass}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={styled}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={tailwind}/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <img src={bootstrap}/>
                            </li>
                            <p className='text'>Passe o cursor do mouse no card para ver a descrição!</p>
                        </SkillsGrid>  
                                       
            </ContainerSkills>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O método `getElementsByClassName` não aceita seletor CSS e você está passando um seletor css para ele, quando na verdade ele só aceita o nome da class, é diferente, no `querySelector` vc pode passar seletor CSS;

O correto seria `document.getElementsByClassName('html')` sem o ponto